# Do affiliate work with Parallel Tracking in Google ads or Bing ads

Tags: google-search, google-ads, bing, affiliate, microsoft

For affiliate offer to work, a user need to go through the affiliate link and it a mandatory. if user did not went through the affiliate link then the commission will not get generated for affiliaters.

Example:

Let say my affiliate link is https://www.affiliatelink.com/offer=123 which redirect to a merchant website https://www.example.com

Now, in simple way i will add https://www.example.com in final url and https://www.affiliatelink.com/offer=123 in tracking template URL.

> **User click -> Tracking template URL (affiliate link) -> Final URL (Merchant link) = Successful commission**

So, when user click, it will click on tracking URL which have affiliate link and then the user will get redirected to merchant page and this how a affiliater get commission if merchant make a any sales.

But, the main problem is google ads introduce a parallel tracking. In parallel tracking when user click ads they directly get landed to Final URL https://www.example.com and the tracking template URL get loaded in back-end.

> **User Click -> Directly landed to final URL (merchant website)**
>
> **Tracking template get loaded in back end.**

[image]

My question is even if the tracking template loaded in back-end, do i still get commission from affiliate network? because i fair i know about affiliate marketing that a visitor should visit through the affiliate link to get any commission.

Important link :

> Parallel Tracking :
> https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7544674
>
> Tracking Template :
> https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7197008?hl=en

Comment: This is a question for the affiliate network, there is no way we can know how their system works.